# Не срабатывает шоткод

Tags: wordpress

Этот элементарный шоткод почему-то не работает! я сделал все, как документации, но даже этот просто шоткод не срабатывает.... В чем может быть причина?
Файл functions.php (темы, которая установлена):

```
//[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

Comment: а где регистрация таксономии?

Comment: вы привели код, добавляющий только кастомный тип поста. добавьте код, регистрирующий таксономию. но вообще, судя по `'taxonomies' => array( 'Movie' )` имена и так разные

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже понял, поэтому и переделал вопрос!

Comment: как вы его используете, этот шорткод?

Comment: @KAGG Design, сам диву даюсь...в одном тестовом проекте не работает,в другом работает...код везде одинаковый,права тоже... не могу понять в чем причина

Comment: покажите, как вы используете шорткод

Comment: в одном и том же файле functions.php, в одной и той же теме, одни и те же права стоят (755 и 644), код такой же, как и в вопросе...Делал по документации codex.wordpress.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шорткод у вас возвращает, а не выводит. 
Пример елементарного шорткода, который выводит "Hello World!":

В functions.php:

```
    function my_shortcode(){
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }

    add_shortcode( 'helloworld', 'my_shortcode' );
```

После этого, в обычном редакторе, в админке например используется в виде `[helloworld]`, а если в php странице или коде так `echo do_shortcode('[helloworld]');`